# Подгрузка контента без обновления страницы, ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, asp.net

Товарищи, предо мной встала следующая задача: реализовать динамическую подгрузку контента на cshtml-страничку без фактической ее перегрузки. То есть чтобы навигация по сайту проходила без перезагрузки страниц. Разработку веду на ASP.NET, что можете посоветовать? Вешать ли что-то вроде ReactJS.Net или попробовать обойтись простыми AJAX? И как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: если вам пару запросов надо получить асинхронно, то ajax. Если целое приложение должно работать без перезагрузок, то SPA - фреймворков для этого полно, хоть React, хоть Angular, хоть Vue - выбирайте что подходит под ваши нужды.

Comment: @tym32167 Как считаете, что из этого лучше «сольётся» с ASP.NET?)

Comment: фронтенду, по сути, без разницы, что на бекенде и наоборот, бекенду все равно, что на фронтенде. Так что технически можно выбирать все, что душе угодно. Я вот начал смотреть в сторону ангуляра, но в моем окружении колбасят на реакте. Но это энтерпрайз, а что вам нужно я не имею понятия. Для сайта-визитки, например, и JQuery подойдет